# How to make sure my function executes after all ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function.Inside this function i have 3 ajax calls. How can i make sure that my another function executes after these ajax calls done?

```
function a(){
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
        $.post("somePage.php").done(function(){
            do stuff here...
        });
    return false;
}
function b(){
    //.....
}
```

will my function b execute after ajax calls done?

Comment: no.... how ever how is b called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until all jquery ajax request are done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

Answer (score 3):

a complete solution will be something like

```
function a() {
    var array = [], xhr;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        xhr = $.post("somePage.php").done(function () {});
        array.push(xhr)
    }
    //create a promise which will be called after all the ajax request are completed
    return $.when.apply($, array);
}

function b() {
    //.....
}

//on succss callback of all the ajax requests created in a call b
a().done(b)
```

Comment: Only potential issue, depending on how this function is called is that it used to return false, now it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Write an increment check which increments on each returned Ajax like below:

```
increments = 0;
$.post("somePage.php").done(function(){
  // Check if the increments are total to 3
  ++increments;
  if(increments == 3) {
    //do something now such as call b();
  }
  //do stuff here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) method allows you to register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed.